# mysite users

Tags: my-site

Edited: I went through this (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx) to make sure all the steps are accounted for. still get the same error. can someone please shed some light on it?

I could not get this work. May be I have missed a step or 2 during mysite setup?

http://Server:7448/Person.aspx?accountname=domain\JohnD

Edited: I even tried this link http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-my-site-sharepoint-2010/ but still same error.

Comment: what happens when you just open "http://Server:7448"? Does your own profile show up?

Comment: What error are you talking about?

Comment: server:7448 shows up as team site. When I click on the my site under my name (upper right side) it re-loads the same page. which is http://server:7448/SitePages/Home.aspx

Comment: I am getting 404 file not found error on person.aspx

Comment: You need to provide descriptive titles, and enough information for a complete stranger to understand what you're trying to do. You give no mention as to what the error message is that you're receiving.

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please {edit} your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for general guidelines.

Comment: Agreed, and not the first time either. @lu you need to step up.  Asking this kind of half finished questions benefits noone, including yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not created a "My Site Host". Your root site of your web application is a team site. Please have a second look at the section "Create the My Site Host Site Collection" in your referenced tutorial.

Comment: You r correct. it seems that who ever created the mysite used a different template instead of mysite. Thanks. I will try that.\

Comment: @I had to delete the sc and re-created with my site template. now they are all happy. Thanks Robert.